# Django 1.5 ImportError: No module named myproject.urls

Tags: django, virtualenv, django-1.5, django-1.4

Im trying to get a project working locally, however when I try and $python manage.py runserver I get the error: ImportError: No module named myproject.urls

I am confident the project is set up properly I feel like something needs to be configured on my end, however I have not been able to solve it. The project structure looks like this

```
/root
  -requirements.txt
  /myproject
    -manage.py
    -urls.py
    /apps
    /settings
     -base.py 
     -local.py
```

settings/base.py

```
ROOT_URLCONF = "myproject.urls"
```

I have set my DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.local

We were on python 1.4 before and now since we moved to 1.5 I havent been able to get the enviro working locally, it is however, working live.

Comment: Well the error already specifies it, there is no `urls.py` in `myproject`. You need to add one. That being said, Django-1.5 is already havily outdated, and no longer supported. So it might be beneficial to migrate to a supported version

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Sorry, there is a urls.py in the myproject directory. That was a typo. Yeah we are migrating up to django 1.9 eventually.

Comment: If the structure you show is accurate, the problem would appear to be a path issue. ``manage.py`` should be above ``/myproject`` in order for ``myproject.urls`` to be valid. Also as @WillemVanOnsem said, upgrade Django! :-)

Comment: @bogeymin  Unfortunately that did not work (the project structure is live). I feel like its something with PYTHONPATH, but im not sure..  We are upgrading!